# Expandable ListView in Fragment, (from AndroidHive)

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I'm trying to use this example http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ in my project.
The main problem is:
I have ListFragment instead of regular Activity.
I put few `getActivity().findViewByID` instead of `findViewByID`, and `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.

App crashes at

```
  // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

I'm just newbie in Android dev. Could someone explain how to adapt example for ListFragment.

Comment: your expListView is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expListView` is null in your code, you need your View that returned on `onCreateView` for finding Expanable View instead of `getActivity()`.

use like following:

```
  expListView = YourView.findViewById(yourId);
```

if this not helped you, post logcat error and fragment code

Example Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View test= inflater.inflate(R.layout.testLayout,
                container, false);
        expListView = test.findViewById(R.id.expanableId);


        return test;
 }
```

Comment: It works, but now after "return MyView" app crashes. Saying 06-07 06:31:41.700    1222-1222/com.example.moneybag.moneybag E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: when you use `ListFragment` you must have listView with `android.R.id.list` in your xml layout, if you don't want that change `ListFragment` to `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

Change your ExpandableListView id in xml.

It should be like  `android:id="@+id/lvList"`

Get it as `ExpandableListView expListView = Your_View.findViewById(R.id.lvList);` in your java File.